# In mesibo do we have any restriction to create user address format?

Tags: mesibo

Im trying to create users in mesibo as some big unique numbers as follows -6044:6003:7aa7ec39a119410da93c109c6b8c4c5e

But looks like these users are not able to send & receive messages.

Please help me is there any format restriction to create users address here.

Is it valid user address - 6044:6003:7aa7ec39a119410da93c109c6b8c4c5e ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No restrictions as long as it is a unique string and does not have HTML symbols for security reasons, it is mentioned here.

https://mesibo.com/documentation/faq/#is-it-required-to-have-an-email-address-or-a-phone-number-to-use-mesibo

> Absolutely not. You can use any valid random string as the user-id.
> All you need to ensure that the user-id is unique across all your
> users. Refer to the mesibo backend API to learn how to create a user.

Try without ":" and see that it works.

Comment: Thanks for response. Now working fine after removing " : "